# after logout, get_current_user_id still holds value

Tags: redirect, logout

I added a login, logout   menu item  to a menu with the following code in `functions.php`. After logout it redirects to the current page. But surprisingly enough, the `get_current_user_id` method still holds the value of the previously logged in user.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'asv_add_usermenu_student', 10, 2 );

     function asv_add_usermenu_student( $items, $args ) {

              if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_student_menu') {

                $items .= "<li ><a href='" .wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ). "'>Log Out</a></li>";

            } elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_student_menu') {

               $items .= '<li > <a href="' . wp_login_url() . '?redirect_to='.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"/>LOG IN</a></li>';
              }
              return $items;
            }
```

How to grt rid of it ?

Comment: `get_current_user_id` does not show up anywhere in your code and the user ID does not persist when I test this. There is something wrong somewhere in code not posted.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, `get_current_user_id` is used in static pages. Let me recheck .